# set android alarm at specific time

Tags: android, date, alarmmanager

i set the alarm at specific time but every time i open the application it will turn on 
this is the code i used :

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0010000,intent,0);

Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Comment: the alarm is set on 5:59:00 but when i leave the app and open it again the alarm will set again ,, how i can avoid this problem and make the alarm set only at 5:59:00 !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Alright, you need to set the alarm to ring the next time it is 5:59:00.
You do this by getting the current time, if its before 5:59:00, set the alarm, if its after 5:59:00 then add a day and set the alarm.  Do it like so:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new Panel(this));

    Date dat  = new Date();//initializes to now
    Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_now.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,5);//set the alarm time
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    if(cal_alarm.before(cal_now)){//if its in the past increment
        cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }
    //SET YOUR AlarmManager here

}
```

I wanted to give you a buildable example, but i don't fully understand alarmmanager yet, so this is what you have.  Built on eclipse 3.5.2 with ADK 15

Comment: yes Chris this is my problem ,, if the time is in the past the alarm is triggered .how to solve it ? wt should i do ?

Comment: Get the current time, then find out how many millis need to elapse until 5:59:00 the next day.
I will see if i can get something coded here in a bit.

Comment: i get the current time using System.currentTimeMillis() and the time in calender i get it using time.getTimeInMillis() do u mean to do sth like this :
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,System.getTimeInMillis()+ (Systrm.getTimeInMillis - time.getTimeInMillis()),pendingIntent);

Comment: cd.add(Calendar.DATE,1); this wt will add ?

Comment: cd.setTime(new Date()); , new Date() needs an argument wt should i put it ?

Comment: @israa Date should initialize to the current time.  And cd.add(Calendar.DATE,1); will add one day to the current date.  So the result is 5 the next day.  To make it robust you will need to check the curent time and only add a day if it is after 5:59

Comment: @israa if i had to guess, id say you are using java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date

Comment: ooh yes, u guessed , i changed it but still same problem!

Comment: thnxxxxx a lot Chris ,,, this is wt i need and the alarm now works fine ^_^

Comment: hey @Chris if i need to set alarms for multiple days, is there a cal_alarm.set(days) type of function? or should i alrmmanager.set() separately for each one?

Edit: Same time multiple days

Comment: trying something like this cal.set(Calendar.SATURDAY,1); hoping 1/0 would be a kind of true/false?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing this code in onCreate function, place it inside any button event or any other event which will be called only on user interaction.
I think, that'll do.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0010000,intent,0);
pendingIntent.cancel();
```

add this 'cancel' method to your code. this will cancel the previous alarm before setting the new one.

Comment: the time 5:59:00 is taken from web server database and i want to notify the user without a button event , i mean in the background but i don't know how to do this

Comment: I agree put it in a button listener, but i doubt that is the problem.

Comment: how frequent will u check the DB for the update of this time (5:59:00)?
if u check, have this alarm set in that method.

Comment: this time will be fixed taken from web server only once , i mean every day at 5:59:00 i want the alarm to be set , to be more clear my app is used for patients and there is a website for doctor , i want the doctor to remind the patient when he should take his medicine . i don't want to use action listener or a button , wt i need is to set the alarm only at this time

Comment: even in this case u would be having a method to check the DB. if the doctor set 5:59 at website, u would be using some piece of code to bring it to the app. are u reading from DB each time the app starts?

Comment: yes , i read the time every time the app starts and i stored it in android database , if there is an update or the time changed in web server i used a function to check that and the time will be updated in android database , all this is done in OnCreate()

Comment: wt i need is to stop triggering the alarm after it is set to specific time , how to do that ?

Comment: added a piece of code to the Answer.
also, use DATE + 1, as suggested by Chris.