# AlarmManager schedule android java

Tags: java, android

I have some schedule in my app, and i need to do some  task in specific time every day(in other time) example at 7:00 in Monday , at 12:00 in Tuesday etc. And schedule in others weeks of month can be different. How can i do this.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139936/set-android-alarm-at-specific-time .

Comment: Sorry, but it cant solve my problem

Comment: Did you try any code ? plus what isn't "solving your problem" ? the link shows an example of Alarm with specific time, you can add specific day also .

Comment: I dont understand how to add different times to different days, can i add next alarm, when the privious finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502441/time-event-listener) will help you figure how to setup events happening at certain times and how to interact with them programmatically.

The main premise is that you use an **AlarmManager** to schedule your events:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent activate = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
AlarmManager alarms ;
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, activate, 0);
alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

and you use a **BroadcastReceiver** to add functionality when that time is reached:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ferry_sound);
    mp.start();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    long[] s = { 0, 100, 10, 500, 10, 100, 0, 500, 10, 100, 10, 500 };
    vibrator.vibrate(s, -1);
 }
}
```

You'll need to register your receiver in your **manifest.xml**

```
<Application ... >
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm" />
...
</Application>
```